# Is there a way to detect if the notification bar has been cleared?

Tags: android, events, notifications

I want to be notified when the user cleared the noficiation bar (clicked on "clear" button).

i mean to that button:

[image]

Is there a way to do that? by broadcast or something?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your own notifications, use [`deleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) to specify a `PendingIntent` to be executed when the user clears your notification.

However, you cannot find out whether that button has been pressed in general, for other notifications than your own.